# ios push notification terminates app

Tags: ios, cordova, apple-push-notifications

I want to launch my app when clicking view button on push notification but my app gets terminated if the app is not in background.

here is my error message from console.

```
Aug  9 10:35:41 unknown listingApp[4527] <Error>: -[__NSCFDictionary absoluteString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1a8b50
Aug  9 10:35:41 unknown listingApp[4527] <Error>: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary absoluteString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1a8b50'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x36df764f __exceptionPreprocess + 114
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x34050c5d objc_exception_throw + 24
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x36dfb1bf -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 102
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x36dfa649 ___forwarding___ + 508
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x36d71180 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 48
    5   listingApp                          0x00002d09 -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 220
    6   UIKit                               0x35c12821 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 772
    7   UIKit                               0x35c0cb65 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 272
    8   UIKit                               0x35be17d7 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1114
    9   UIKit                               0x35be1215 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 44
    10  UIKit                               0x35be0c53 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 5090
    11  GraphicsServices                    0x3651be77 PurpleEventCallback + 666
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x36dcea97 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 26
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x36dd083f __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 166
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x36dd160d __CFRunLoopRun + 520
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x36d61ec3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 230
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x36d61dcb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 58
    17  UIKit                               0x35c0bd49 -[UIApplication _run] + 372
    18  UIKit                               0x35c09807 UIApplicationMain + 670
    19  listingApp                          0x00002b93 main + 78
    20  listingApp                          0x00002b0c start + 52
)
Aug  9 10:35:41 unknown UIKitApplication:co.isale.isale[0xc768][4527] <Notice>: terminate called after throwing an instance of '
Aug  9 10:35:41 unknown UIKitApplication:co.isale.isale[0xc768][4527] <Notice>: NSException
Aug  9 10:35:41 unknown UIKitApplication:co.isale.isale[0xc768][4527] <Notice>: '
Aug  9 10:35:41 unknown ReportCrash[4528] <Notice>: Formulating crash report for process listingApp[4527]
Aug  9 10:35:41 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Warning>: (UIKitApplication:co.isale.isale[0xc768]) Job appears to have crashed: Abort trap: 6
```

and this is the beginning of my didFinishlaunchWithOptions

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{   

NSLog(@"didFinishLaunchingWithOptions");
viewController.webView = webView;
[viewController.view addSubview:webView];


// read from UISupportedInterfaceOrientations (or UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~iPad, if its iPad) from -Info.plist
NSArray* supportedOrientations = [self parseInterfaceOrientations:
                                           [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"UISupportedInterfaceOrientations"]];

// read from PhoneGap.plist in the app bundle
NSDictionary *temp = [[self class] getBundlePlist:@"PhoneGap"];
settings = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:temp];

viewController = [ [ PhoneGapViewController alloc ] init ];

NSNumber *useLocation          = [settings objectForKey:@"UseLocation"];
NSString *topActivityIndicator = [settings objectForKey:@"TopActivityIndicator"];


// The first item in the supportedOrientations array is the start orientation (guaranteed to be at least Portrait)
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:[[supportedOrientations objectAtIndex:0] intValue]];

// push notification 
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
// end of push notification
```

this code is from another delegate file called AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{


NSArray *keyArray = [launchOptions allKeys];
if ([launchOptions objectForKey:[keyArray objectAtIndex:0]]!=nil) 
{
    NSURL *url = [launchOptions objectForKey:[keyArray objectAtIndex:0]];
    self.invokeString = [url absoluteString];
    NSLog(@"listingApp launchOptions = %@",url);
}

return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}
```

please help?
many thanks  thanks :)

Comment: You need to show some code as well.

Comment: sorry :) as you can see this is my first post, will post code now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be calling `absoluteString` on a dictionary, where you probably meant to do it on an `NSURL` object.

Re your latest code sample:

You are doing something very strange, trying to find the first key in the `launchOptions` dictionary. This is not how to use dictionaries. You should use the keys (listed [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006728) under *Launch Options Keys*) directly, like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    NSURL *url = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey]

    if (url)
    {
        self.invokeString = [url absoluteString];
        NSLog(@"listingApp launchOptions = %@", url);
    }

    return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}
```

Comment: sorry dude crazy work schedule won't let me get back at it just yet :( will try it soon!

Comment: that code worked like a charm :) thank you thank you thank you @Pnutus :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you haven't implemented the method

`- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo`

This method is called when a notification is received.

Comment: No, I don't think so — notice the actual error is about a call to `absoluteString`. This is probably a memory management error.

Comment: thanks ibeitia for quick response, unfortunately didReceiveRemoteNotificaion will only work if the app is in background.